# Swift: imageWithData not available

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

I am creating a UIImage object in swift by passing image data to it. Similar to how its done in objective-c

```
UIImage imageWithData
```

However, i see error that says: imageWithData is not available for swift.

What is the alternative for imageWithData for Swift ?

Comment: What's the exact code you're using?

Comment: The methods `initWithX` become an initializer with a parameter of `x`. Thus, `initWithData:...` becomes`UIImage(data:...)`.

Comment: Did you read the complete error message? My Xcode displays `error: 'imageWithData' is unavailable: use object construction 'UIImage(data:)'`

Answer (score 8):

I can't find the `imageWithData` class method in the UIImage documentation, however you could use `init(data:)` data method:

```
let image:UIImage = UIImage(data:youDataHere);
```

Comment: When i print the album art image i extracted from an MP3 file. Its a series of hexadecimal numbers. Is that considered as NSData ?

Comment: Yes, NSData is a series of hex number.

Comment: I figured it out, my image data was of string type. I returned it as NSData type and that worked

Comment: let image = UIImage(data:yourData!)  could be better.